# Avoid pgrep in csh

Tags: shell-script, grep, csh

I got that code

```
foreach pr  (`pgrep "$NAME"`)
```

And I try to avoid pgrep:

```
foreach pr  (`grep "$NAME" | awk '{$2}'`)
```

but that does not really work.
(later with that pr should be the PID printed out of special tasks

Comment: `ps -ea | grep "$NAME" | awk '{print $1}'` ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you try to avoid `pgrep`?

With the change from `pgrep` to `grep` you forgot to specify a data source:

```
for pr in `ps -ef|grep "$NAME"|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: at least there is no error report anymore... but it is not working the way it should... using pgrep works but on my other machine pgrep is not supported

Comment: Try to debug the command by issuing pieces of it. First run `ps -ef |grep "$NAME"`, then add the `awk` part. Verify the content of `$NAME`. Maybe there is no such process at all.

Comment: I can't fix it... I have a similar program in sh do you think the problem is more easy to handle there?

Comment: @JuM Yes; csh scripting is awkward. You pretty much always want to go for Bourne scripting or a "real" language.